# How to Load Byte-Array on background of Hololens

Tags: c#, hololens

I create an application for Hololens with Unity 2020.3.12f with the MixedRealityToolKit.
I have a problem loading a file to a byte array in background of the Hololens.

To visualise png-grafics ( > 100 files) on my Hololens App, i create sprites dynamicly from ByteArrays.
To load an image (~96 KB) into a byte-Array with `File.ReadAllBytes` takes around 300 ms (very slow).
To keep the process of updating the shown image fast, the Byte-Arrays of all images should be preloaded on a GameObjects script.

I decided to load 20 files into ByteArray and show up the first image as sprite.

After this process the other files should be loaded in the backgroud, so the App still allows interaction. The function I Call from a Button should look like:

```
public void LoadSomething()
{
  UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(async () =>
  {
    #Load First Byte-Arrays and show up first Image

    #Load the rest of the Bytes-Arrays without blocking Interaction on App
    LoadBytes();
  }, false);
}
```

The files to load are stored as Storagefiles on a Gameobject "Manager".
The function for loading could be like:

```
private void LoadBytes()
{
  foreach (Storagefile storageFile in manager.listOfStorageFiles)
  { 
     byte[] filedata = File.ReadAllBytes(storageFile.Path);
     manager.byteList.Add(fileData);
  }
}
```

I tried to start the function with `Task.Run(() => LoadBytes )`, but this freezes the UI and nothing happens. I think there is a problem to work with a GameObject on CPU.

Have anyone a solution for calling this function from the UIThread and still keep my UI interactive ?

Comment: Why not do this asynchronously? Since you have any I/O-bound needs, it is recommended to improve LoadBytes() as an asynchronous method that performs a non-blocking wait on the background job.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have any I/O-bound needs, it is recommended to improve `LoadBytes()` as an asynchronous method that performs a non-blocking wait on the background job. For more information please see: [Asynchronous programming patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/)